# Is there a way to white-list <br /> and <div> tags without adding additional buttons?

Tags: c#, ajaxcontroltoolkit, htmleditorextender

When I save text/html from a text box using the HTML Editor Extender it keeps on stripping out new lines and divs.

I have found the why:

> if a tag is not on a white list (in other words, not needed by an
>   HtmlEditorExtender button) then it gets stripped. We want to do
>   everything that we can to prevent Cross-Site Scripting attacks so we
>   need to limit the types of tags, attributes, and attribute values
>   which you are allowed to use. If you set the HtmlEditorExtender
>   property EnableSanitization=”false” then no stripping occurs — but
>   then you open yourself up to Cross-Site Scripting attacks.

http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2012/06/25/announcing-the-june-2012-release-of-the-ajax-control-toolkit.aspx#comment-4842

And I currently have the follow tools enabled on the toolbar:

```
<ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExtender1" 
    TargetControlID="txtBody" DisplaySourceTab="false" 
    runat="server" Enabled="True">
    <Toolbar> 
        <ajaxToolkit:Bold />
        <ajaxToolkit:Italic />
        <ajaxToolkit:Underline />
        <ajaxToolkit:InsertOrderedList />
        <ajaxToolkit:InsertUnorderedList />
        <ajaxToolkit:CreateLink />
        <ajaxToolkit:UnLink />
        <ajaxToolkit:RemoveFormat />
    </Toolbar>
</ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

I added the button `<ajaxToolkit:JustifyLeft />` and `<div>` tags are no longer being stripped, but ideally I don't want to allow additional buttons.

Question:

**Is there a way to white-list `<br />` and `<div>` tags without adding additional buttons?**

Any other options that you guys can think of?

Comment: so we are still not able to white list the tags we want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding any justify button will make the htmleditor extender usable in internet explorer.

```
<ajaxToolkit:Justifyleft /> 
<ajaxToolkit:JustifyCenter /> 
<ajaxToolkit:JustifyRight /> 
<ajaxToolkit:JustifyFull />
```

without these buttons, everything gets stripped and  tags are not accepted. You mention that you have been able to get tags br accepted also, which button did you add to allow this to happen. This will make the htmleditorextender usable. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I have not yet seen which button would allow BR tags to get past validation, only DIV. Adding a justify button is how I am currently making the DIVs work. It's nice to see that others have the same question.

Comment: yes it's a common problem. I have now decided to disable sanitization and do all my own sanitizing. This is a potential source to get you started http://eksith.wordpress.com/2011/06/14/whitelist-santize-htmlagilitypack/